# Derivative of function involving absolute value

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Could anyone help me with differentiating $|x|^5$ and **$\frac{|x|^3}{(1+x^2)^8}$**?

I used the way we differentiate $|x|$ via substitution, i.e.
[enter link description here](http://www.analyzemath.com/calculus/Differentiation/absolute_value.html)
 It fails on the two functions I have.

Hope someone could suggest the right methods to differentiate functions involves absolute value. Especially, please help with a good way to differentiate the second function.

Answer (score 2):

Just do it piecewise.  Let $f(x) = |x|^5$.  On the interal $(0, \infty)$, $f(x) = x^5$, so $f'(x) = 5x^4$ for $x \in (0, \infty)$.  On the interval $(-\infty,0)$, $f(x) = -x^5$, so $f'(x) = -5x^4$ for $x \in (-\infty, 0)$.  The question remains whether $f$ is differentiable at $0$.  By definition, the derivative of $f$ at $0$ (if it even exists) is the limit $$\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h} = \lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{|h|^5}{h}$$ But actually, this limit does exist.  It is $0$.  To see this, just check the limit as $h$ comes from the right and come from the left exist and are both equal to $0$.  So $f'(0)$ is defined and equal to $0$.

Comment: could you use your idea to my second function? I have clarify the function, see edited.

Comment: Just try the same thing lol, check if the limit as $h$ goes to $0$ exists when $x = 0$.

Comment: it will not work well...but i worked out sth myself...

Answer (score 0):

Try to differentiate $|x|$ at $x=0$ using the definition of the derivative. This will fail. Then try to differentiate $|x|x$ at $x=0$. This will work and you will get the value $0$. Then write $|x|^5 = (|x|x)x^3$ and use the product rule.

Comment: It is not differentiable there. You have $(|x|-0)/(x-0) = sign(x)$ for nonzero x, so the difference coefficient can not converge as $x$ tends to zero. This problem is not present for $|x|x$, nor is there a problem for the other function.